# How to avoid False positives in yolov5 object detection?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I am training a yolov5 model for golf ball detection. I am facing serious issues with false detection as the color of golf ball is white. The model is detecting similar shapes with white color as golf ball moreover it is only detecting a golf ball in few scenarios like at a specific distance. I have a large amount of dataset annotated on roboflow (most probably 60,000 annotated images for golf ball). I am using yolov5s.pt as I have to deploy the model on mobile devices. If anyone knows how to tackle this issue then please do mention about it.

I have modified and improved my dataset several times to cover multiple scenarios in my data. But this didn't worked at all. mAP0.5 for ball is 95+ but still it results in false positives.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without more information (which isn't provided in the question).  Perhaps one natural approach is to gather more data: gather images that are representative of the scenarios where the model makes errors, and annotate them.

Every model will have false positives.  It is unlikely that any model will be perfect -- every model makes errors.  It is simply a matter of how frequently or rarely those errors happen -- but it is unlikely you will ever drive the error rate to 0.

Comment: What kind of information do you require to understand the problem more effectively?